# Is there a way to add an array of strings into the options argument for an input?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have an array of floats:

```
[1.08286, 11491.0, 1.10171, 11365.0, 1.09248, 11297.0, 1.09591, 11281.0, 1.08522, 11153.0, 1.09652, 11083.0, 1.08246, 10995.0, 1.08956, 10962.0, 1.08299, 10936.0, 1.08874, 10876.0]
```

I want these to be within a dropdown that the user can choose from.

I have converted them into an array of Strings:

```
stringArray = array.new_string(size = 0)
for i = 0 to array.size(originalFloatArray) - 1
    array.push(stringArray, str.tostring(originalFloatArray[i]))

userSelectedOption = input.string("Default Option", title="Select an Option", options=stringArray)
```

but the error I always seem to get is: `` The `input.string()` function cannot use `stringArray` as its 'options' argument. This parameter accepts a tuple of 'const string' types. ``

Is this something that's unachievable in Pinescript, or is it something I'm doing incorrectly?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide static const values.

> options (tuple of const string values: [val1, val2, ...]) A list of options to choose from.

If your numbers are static, you can simply include them in the options, as strings or even floats. In case these should be calculated dynamically, this is not possible.

```
userSelectedOption = input.float(1.08286, title="Select an Option", options= [1.08286, 11491.0, 1.10171, 11365.0, 1.09248, 11297.0, 1.09591, 11281.0, 1.08522, 11153.0, 1.09652, 11083.0, 1.08246, 10995.0, 1.08956, 10962.0, 1.08299, 10936.0, 1.08874, 10876.0])
```

Comment: If I `log.info()` my array, it prints like: `[1.10093, 11926.0, 1.0723799999999999, 11726.0, 1.08177, 11686.0, 1.0755, 11665.0, 1.08047, 11631.0, 1.07723, 11627.0, 1.10171, 11365.0, 1.09248, 11297.0, 1.09591, 11281.0, 1.08522, 11153.0]`, which, I believe, the syntax matches your example.

When I call that array within `options`, it errors with `Cannot call 'input.float' with argument 'options'='array'. An argument of 'float[]' type was used but a '[const float...]' is expected.`

Comment: It's because in pine script a construct that would look like an array in js/php etc. is a so called tuple. You cannot use an array definition there. Check out the requirements regarding arguments: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input.float   - you'll have to define your input options as I provided statically in advance.